# Uncaught ReferenceError when trying to change js function into coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: er is not defined
```

This is the code ..

```
{CompositeDisposable} = require 'atom'
lib = require 'lib'

module.exports =
  subscriptions: null

  activate: ->
    @subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable
    @subscriptions.add atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
      'my-package:convert': => @convert()

  deactivate: ->
    @subscriptions.dispose()

  convert: ->
    console.log 'Convert text!'
    if editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
      console.log editor.getText()
      lib.process(editor.getText() (er files)) ->
        console.log 'All files ..'
        listFiles(files)

  listFiles: (files) ->
    for fileName in Object.keys(files)
      first = files[fileName].first
      second = files[fileName].second
      third = files[fileName].third
      console.log 'Done'
```

This is the `javascript` I'm trying to change to `coffeescript` inside `convert()` ..

```
lib.process(text, function (er, files) {
  console.log('All files ..');
  listFiles(files);
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `lib.process(editor.getText(), (er, files) -> ...)`? Look at the transpiled JavaScript and you'll see why your CoffeeScript doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
lib.process(editor.getText() (er files)) ->
```

is not correct, since it's missing the commas needed to separate the parameters.

When trying to transpile the line you wrote to JS it would look like this:

```
lib.process(editor.getText()(er(files)))(function() {});
```

When trying to migrate JS to coffee, it's sometimes a good idea to start with http://js2.coffee/ and start from there.
Always look at the transpiled JS result in order to check if everything will work as expected